# Referencing an object array for cascading select options with angular-formly

Tags: angular-formly

I'm creating a form which will have field options dependent upon choices earlier in the form, referencing a JSON array. I've studied the Cascade Select example, but haven't quite wrapped my head around how the controllers work in it. Would someone mind helping me adapt the concepts of the Cascade Select example to reference a JSON array?

[Here is a link](http://jsbin.com/kureyuwadi/edit?html,js,output) to a JS Bin illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish (be sure to "Run with JS"). I would like fields whose options are populated with respect to an array and are filtered based on previous selection. I've figured out how to do the first level of options for selecting a sport with a simple for-loop function passed to the "options" argument in the form element; but I need a hand moving to the next stage. Ideally, I would like to have more depth; i.e. Pick a Sport > Pick a Team > Pick a Player; but I should be able to figure it out with just the first filtered select options.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is totally unrelated to angular-formly. Your data model is not properly modeled, you should use the concept of **foreign keys**. A more appropriate modeling would be:

```
  var sports = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Soccer'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Basketball'
  }];

  var teams = [{
      id: 1,
      fk: 1,
      name: 'Bayern Munich'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      fk: 1,
      name: 'Real Madrid'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      fk: 2,
      name: 'Cleveland'
  }];

  var player = [{
      id: 1,
      fk: 1,
      name: 'Mario Götze'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      fk: 2,
      name: 'Javier Hernandez'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      fk: 3,
      name: 'LeBron James'
  }];
```

A working example is shown here: http://output.jsbin.com/jinaca

Comment: Thank you for this, I will look at this closely tomorrow afternoon. I'm not experienced with foreign keys, so I'll need to do some research there. Here's my initial reaction: If I were to extend the example to draw from a database, rather than a static model, would I need to design objects added to the database in this way? Are the two models not essentially equivalent? It seems like such a model could be generated from the first.

Comment: A relational db should be normalized and modeled like that IMHO.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for helping out with this. And, I don't know why I didn't see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742748/angular-formly-nested-selects) before, so I'm sorry I made you deal with a similar thing twice. :p

Comment: I can't seem to find good examples/tutorials on this principle, so sorry to ask you more about this. (If you know of any, that'd be great.) Could you use foreign keys to avoid having to duplicate data? For example, say I wanted Mario Gotze to be on both Real Madrid and Bayern Munich, but I didn't want two Mario Gotze entries, would that be possible? I'm playing around now with your JS Bin to see if I can accomplish that, but I haven't had any luck yet.